# Synonymise tag [word-meaning]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Should the tag [word-meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-meaning) be synonymised with [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning)? So [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) should be the primary tag and [word-meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-meaning) would be the synonym.

I think [word-meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-meaning) adds nothing. But maybe I'm not nuanced enough.

Answer (score 2):

Since there isn't [phrase-meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-meaning), it makes sense to make [word-meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-meaning) synonym of [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning).

If there were [phrase-meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-meaning), I would suggest that as synonym of [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) too.

If there are questions using [word-meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-meaning), and questions using [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning), then the two tags should be merged, and [word-meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-meaning) made synonym of [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning). That is an operation moderators can do from a single page: the same page used to merge two tags.

Answer (score 1):

These are now synonyms, but they are not merged.

[image: tag syn results]

They still have separate counts: [word-meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-meaning) shows 62 and [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) shows 3,392.

What does that mean, given that they are synonyms?  Do we have to request a merge for each of these?

I seems really silly to have singular and plural forms (like [tense](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tense) and [tenses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tenses)) ever be separate tags.